# Move SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting database to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Has anyone moved the reporting database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a SQL Server 2014, but kept the SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow here. You've asked a "yes or no" question here; personally, no I haven't. What are you actually asking here though. I'm guessing that you're after a step by step guide on how to do this (if it can be done). Stack Overflow is for asking specific coding questions, not for guide requests. I'd suggest searching via your favourite search engine, having a go yourself, and then, if you have problems, then post what you've tried and the problems you're having. Right now, I'm afraid this is too vague to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I am looking to see if anyone has made a move like this before.  If They were able to successfully connect SSRS 2008 to a database sitting on a 2014 SQL Server.

Comment: But, as I said, that's simply a "yes or no" question; you aren't actually asking for any help here. What is it you need help with? Stack Overflow is a website for asking specific coding questions; what is yours?

Comment: There's no particular reason to assume this won't work; SQL Server 2014 supports the 2008 R2 compat level and SQL Server is otherwise highly backwards compatible (query performance excepted). If you're intent on waiting around for someone who's done exactly this so they can swap stories with you, though, I suspect you'll be waiting for quite a long time. You're much better off just trying yourself (using a backup) and come back if you run into any actual trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I have not seen any documentation, articles or message board posts so I thought I would see if anyone had insight on this particular issue. I appreciate it!  I plan to use the migration article Microsoft posted and hope it works without issue.